# jira regular expression to extract location for all.js is wrong on documentation

Tags: jira, add-on, jira-plugin

So Im writing a jira connect add-on and I was having issues loading the location of the all.js  following the code from here [connect-cookbook](https://developer.atlassian.com/static/connect/docs/1.1.33/guides/connect-cookbook.html#all.js)

because my app was running on a cloud instance that didn't send cp as part of the params as in https://test.jiraserver.com/helloworld.html?tz=America%2FGuatemala&loc=en-US&user_id=&user_key=&xdm_e=https%3A%2F%2Fanswer42-jira.atlassian.net&xdm_c=channel-fe9fc149-d649-4329-a9d3-a1a9087fb5d0__hello-world&cp=&lic=none&cv=1.1.55%20HTTP/1.1

note that the cp is empty.

Answer (score 0):

to fix this simply change the regular expression a bit

from `var codedParam = (new RegExp(param + '=([^&]+)')).exec(window.location.search)[1];`

to `var codedParam = (new RegExp(param + '=([^&]*)')).exec(window.location.search)[1];`

since cp is optional.